# Update a multiple records with duplicate column value

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that identify how many times a `ChassisNo` was use:

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY ChassisNo
        ORDER BY datecreated ASC
    ) row_num,
    CollateralType,
    LoanID,
    ClientID,
    CollateralID,
    PlateNo,
    ChassisNo,
    EngineNo,
    datecreated,
    PreparedBy
FROM 
    TestAllLoanWithCollaterals
```

**Result:**

[image]

I highlighted an example of duplicated `chassisno` three times, some of the `chassisno` are duplicated 5 times or so, but the main thing is, how can I update all records with the same details with the latest `chassisno`

**Expected result**
based on the highlighted example above:

[image]

The yellow highlight is the latest record based on the `datecreated` column and always the last `row_num` of each `chassisno`. the blue highlight is the columns that should be updated.

I am thinking of using the Database Cursor but I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You may use an update join involving your original table and the logic you have already defined:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ChassisNo ORDER BY datecreated DESC) rn
    FROM TestAllLoanWithCollaterals
)

UPDATE a
SET
    CollateralType = b.CollateralType
    LoanID = b.LoanID
    ClientID = b.ClientID
    CollateralID = b.CollateralID
    PlateNo = b.PlateNo
    EngineNo = b.EngineNo
    datecreated = b.datecreated
    PreparedBy = b.PreparedBy
FROM TestAllLoanWithCollaterals a
INNER JOIN cte b
    ON a.ChassisNo = b.ChassisNo
WHERE
    b.rn = 1;
```

Note that the above update logic simply overwrites all fields among duplicate by chassis to use those of the record which were most recently updated in the group.